# printw() not working in while loop

Tags: c, ncurses

For some reason whenever I try to printw a string it wont refresh the screen when I enter a while loop... what could I be doing wrong?

```
#include<ncurses.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

int main()
{

    initscr(); /* Start curses mode */
    while(1);
    {
        printw("hi there");
        refresh();
        sleep(1);
    }
    endwin(); /* End curses mode */
    return 0;
}
```

It just hangs at the terminal and does nothing. It is definitly running because my cpu ramps up but nothing shows. If I remove the the while loop, it works just fine. FYI, i'm testing it out because a timer will go here and will be showing aditional data that is changing constantly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's because you have a semi-colon at the end of your `while` condition:

```
while(1);  //  <---  Remove the ;
```

Any decent compiler should warn you about this.